# Easy way to mock chained method calls in Easymock

Tags: easymock

Is there a simple way to mock this call:

```
objectA.getB().getC();
```

right now the way I do this is:

```
A mockA = EasyMock.createMock(A.class);
B mockB = EasyMock.createMock(B.class);
C mockC = EasyMock.createMock(C.class);

expect(mockA.getB()).andReturn(mockB);
expect(mockB.getC()).andReturn(mockC);
```

This is a bit of an overkill since all I care is to get mockC. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is about EasyMock, but i can't just sit on my hands and not tell you about Mockito.
The mocking you would like to do, is fairly easy in Mockito.

```
A mockA = Mockito.mock(A.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
C mockC = Mockito.mock(C.class);
Mockito.when(mockA.getB().getC()).thenReturn(mockC);
```

Note that Mockito started off as enhancement to EasyMock, you may read more about it here: https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockitoVSEasyMock

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't – if you want to replace `A`, `B` and `C` in your test with mocks, you need three mock objects.

Another approach is to use the real `A` and `B` classes, and only to replace `C` with a mock object. Then your unit test would test

1. the class that contains `objectA.getB().getC()`
2. `A`
3. `B`

as a "unit" together. Whether this makes sense or not, depends on the concrete scenario.